# OBB vs OBB and resolve/response for 2D game

Tags: opengl, c++, collision-detection, movement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OBB vs OBB Collision Detection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25397/obb-vs-obb-collision-detection)

How can I detect if a rotated OBB intersects with another rotated OBB and resolve it so both OBB objects don't go further into each other.
I want to use it for space ship collision.
I'm using C++ and OpenGL for my project.